# Add an Actuator Button to Grafana Dashboard

Tags: grafana

Hi everyone and Thank You for reading. I have  built a dashboard with Grafana. The sensor readings comes to me from a MQTT broker and are stored in Inflixdb. Now I want to add a button on the Dashboard in order to toggle an actuator (a water pump). Can you help me and suggest me how to do? I do not see any widget in Grafana to add an actuator.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is an anser https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel/

Comment: Roberto - perhaps you should add your suggestion as an answer? Ie a link, the name of the plugin and why it would be suitable?

Comment: I think to  have found a suitable grafana plugin that can activate/deacttivate  an actuator by posting a value with a call api rest. The name of this plugin that can be easily donwloaded and istalled in the grafana is cloudspout button panel plugin. and can be found at  https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel/

Comment: These comments look like one of them should be an answer. Please propose it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think to have found a suitable grafana plugin that can activate/deacttivate an actuator by posting a value with a call api rest. The name of this plugin that can be easily donwloaded and istalled in the grafana is cloudspout button panel plugin. and can be found at [grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel/)